# Android app crash on app start calling bunch of GC call on marshmallow and lower version

Tags: android

I been working in this app for a while and some module are already finish, I assign the minimum SDK version to 16 and target is 27 the app is working fine then suddenly for example the login activity before it was working now I got this problem on all my Activity as long as the app started a bunch of GC call happen and the app crash. and the app is working on API Level 24

```
04-20 11:33:26.307 20181-20181 I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-20 11:33:26.662 20181-20181 I/art: Starting a blocking GC Explicit
04-20 11:33:26.688 20181-20181 I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 
16658(848KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 7MB/12MB, paused 
249us total 25.863ms
04-20 11:33:26.812 20181-20238 E/StudioProfiler: Studio Profilers encountered 
an unexpected error. Consider reporting a bug, including logcat output below.
See also: https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html#studio-bugs

Failed to capture application

04-20 11:33:26.821 20181-20181 V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.wog.himolly
04-20 11:33:26.823 20181-20238 V/StudioProfiler: Acquiring Application for Events
04-20 11:33:26.981 20181-20181 V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
04-20 11:33:27.036 20181-20181 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-20 11:33:27.050 20181-20181 V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.wog.himolly
        Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
04-20 11:33:27.250 20181-20263 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-20 11:33:27.307 20181-20263 I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : d842ad3, Ia10634f51b
    Build Date                       : 01/04/16
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
    Local Branch                     : mybranch17585849
    Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BR.1.2.6_rb1.7
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
04-20 11:33:27.313 20181-20263 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-20 11:33:34.271 20181-20181 V/BoostFramework: mAcquireFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquire(int,int[])
    mReleaseFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockRelease()
    mAcquireTouchFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquireTouch(android.view.MotionEvent,android.util.DisplayMetrics,int,int[])
    mIOPStart method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStart(int,java.lang.String)
    mIOPStop method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStop()
04-20 11:33:34.275 20181-20181 V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@bec09cc
04-20 11:33:34.700 20181-20181 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-20 11:33:35.618 20181-20191 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 134838(21MB) AllocSpace objects, 14(12MB) LOS objects, 0% free, 86MB/86MB, paused 904us total 800.604ms
04-20 11:33:35.798 20181-20191 I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 95778(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 3(9MB) LOS objects, 14% free, 91MB/107MB, paused 526us total 179.163ms
04-20 11:33:36.114 20181-20181 I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:36.155 20181-20191 I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 102419(16MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(24MB) LOS objects, 15% free, 87MB/103MB, paused 460us total 188.308ms
04-20 11:33:36.155 20181-20181 I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 40.609ms for cause Alloc
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:36.279 20181-20181 I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:36.287 20181-20181 I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 7.760ms for cause Alloc
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:36.364 20181-20181 I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:36.371 20181-20193 I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:36.442 20181-20240 I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:36.472 20181-20191 I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 49567(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(21MB) LOS objects, 14% free, 98MB/114MB, paused 461us total 184.882ms
04-20 11:33:36.472 20181-20181 I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 108.267ms for cause Alloc
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:36.472 20181-20193 I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 101.522ms for cause Alloc
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:36.472 20181-20240 I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 30.769ms for cause Alloc
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:36.765 20181-20181 I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:36.785 20181-20181 I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 77130(12MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 98MB/114MB, paused 443us total 19.318ms
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:36.934 20181-20181 I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 29(1744B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 98MB/114MB, paused 437us total 149.163ms
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:37.091 20181-20181 I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15(416B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 98MB/114MB, paused 454us total 156.496ms
    Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 49MB allocation
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:37.245 20181-20181 I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8(240B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 98MB/114MB, paused 448us total 153.720ms
04-20 11:33:37.245 20181-20181 W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 51394504 byte allocation with 16776144 free bytes and 29MB until OOM"
04-20 11:33:37.245 20181-20181 I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:37.250 20181-20181 I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(544B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 98MB/114MB, paused 431us total 5.082ms
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:37.399 20181-20181 I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15(448B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 98MB/114MB, paused 434us total 148.573ms
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:37.553 20181-20181 I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8(240B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 98MB/114MB, paused 448us total 153.768ms
    Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 49MB allocation
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-20 11:33:37.710 20181-20181 I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12(352B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 98MB/114MB, paused 530us total 156.376ms
    Starting a blocking GC HomogeneousSpaceCompact
04-20 11:33:38.113 20181-20181 I/art: HomogeneousSpaceCompact marksweep + semispace GC freed 5(160B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 98MB/114MB, paused 403.065ms total 403.065ms
04-20 11:33:38.113 20181-20181 W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 51394504 byte allocation with 16769200 free bytes and 29MB until OOM"
04-20 11:33:38.114 20181-20181 E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 51394504 byte allocation with 16769200 free bytes and 29MB until OOM
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
        at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
        at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
        at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
        at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:343)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:60)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:44)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:86)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
04-20 11:33:38.114 20181-20181 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20181 SIG: 9
```

LoginActvity.class

```
    public class LoginActivity extends BaseClass {
    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    @BindView(R.id.txt_email)
    EditText txtEmail;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_password)
    EditText txtPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this)
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_submit)
    public void submit(View view) {
        hideKeyboard();


        if (validation){

        }else{
            Map map = new HashMap();
            map.put(APIKey.ACTION, APIAction.LOGIN);
            map.put("email", txtEmail.getText().toString());
            map.put("password", txtPassword.getText().toString());
            sendRequest(map, 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAPIResponse(JSONObject data, Map map, int responseId) {
        super.onAPIResponse(data, map, responseId);
        // parse server response
    }
}
```

BaseClass

```
public abstract class BaseClass extends AppCompatActivity implements APIResponse {

    private static final String TAG = "ActivityBaseClass";
    private CoordinatorLayout layoutRoot;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout layoutSwipe;
    private Snackbar snackbar;

    public void hideKeyboard() {
        //.....
    }

    public void sendRequest(Map map, int requestId) {
        new APIRequest(map, requestId).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestBegin() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAPIResponse(JSONObject data, Map map, int responseId) {
        if (snackbar != null)
            snackbar.dismiss();
    }

    public void onRequestBegin(int requestId) {
        onRequestBegin();
    }

    public void errorNotification(String message) {
       //......
    }

    private class APIRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private RequestBody requestBody;
        private Request request;

        private Map map;
        private int requestId;
        private OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        private APIRequest(Map map) {
            this.map = map;
            requestId = 0;
        }

        private APIRequest(Map map, int requestId) {
            this.map = map;
            this.requestId = requestId;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            requestBody = RequestBody.create(Constants.JSON, new JSONObject(map).toString());

            request = new Request.Builder().url(Config.BASE_URL).post(requestBody).build();

            if (requestId == 0)
                onRequestBegin();
            else
                onRequestBegin(requestId);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
                return response.body().string();
            } catch (IOException e)     {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result != null) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (jsonObject != null)
                        onAPIResponse(jsonObject, map, requestId);
                }
            } else
                onRequestFail("Can't connect right now", map, requestId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there might be multiple memory leaks that's why GC is called so frequently which consumes your application space and crash your application

Comment: It was just a login activity and it was working fine before.

Comment: if possible post your login code and also do check that you are not performing some heavy operation on main thread as well

Comment: It was working fine on API level 24, ill post the login code

Comment: Try increasing Java Heap size. I hope it will get resolved

Comment: I tried increasing the heap size same error.

Comment: I can't see your xml layout but my guess would be that you have a big background image loading directly from your xml